# Oracle syslog auditing vs oracle vault

Tags: oracle, security, audit-trail

I've a confusion in regards to enabling auditing (audit trial) syslog auditing on Oracle and oracle vault.

From my point of view, syslog auditing is more related to the operating system when user logs in and out with oracle user:

```
*.audit_sys_operations=TRUE
*.audit_syslog_level='local1.warning'
*.audit_trail='OS'
```

On the other hand, oracle vault "restricts access to specific areas in an Oracle database from any user, including users who have administrative access"

I can't see the main difference and sometimes I see them correlated, can you please clear my confusion.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"oracle vault" is not a product. There are in fact similarly two products, Oracle Database Vault and Oracle Audit Vault.

Database Vault is not an auditing product, it is a security product. It allows us to define security policies. The point about Database Vault is that, properly implemented, not even DBAs can work around it. Whereas DBAs can avoid regular security measures such as VPD because they have the necessary privileges to switch FGAC policies off (and cover their tracks).

Audit Vault does not create an audit trail. It is a secure repository for audit information. So it is complementary to AUDIT or Fine-Grained Auditing. In fact Audit Vault can store auditing data from non-Oracle databases [such as DB2 and SQL Server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37100_01/doc.121/e27776/plugin_specific.htm#CHDCCIEE).

The other point about the two Vault products is that they both require additional licenses on top of the Enterprise Edition license.